# How to write test cases for custom errors?

Tags: solidity, unittesting, chai, custom-errors

I have a smart contract here that have mints NFTs and claim reward functions, and I have used `custom errors` instead of `require`

```
error stakeNotOver();

 function claimReward(uint256 stakeId) external nonReentrant returns (bool){
        if(addressStaked[_msgSender()] == false)
        revert notParticipant();
        if(stakerTokensInfo[_msgSender()][stakeId].endTS > block.timestamp)
        revert stakeNotOver();
        if(stakerTokensInfo[_msgSender()][stakeId].claimed > 0)
        revert alreadyClaimed();
        for(uint256 i =0; i< stakingId[msg.sender].length; i++){
            if(stakeId != stakingId[msg.sender][i])
            revert NoSuchStakingExists();
        }
```

but now as I am writing test cases using `chai`, I don't know how to deal with them. I tried something I found on the internet but it didn't work either

```
    it("Should not unstake if the time is not completed", async function () {

        await testToken.connect(owner).transfer(hyperStaking.address, 1000)
        await hyperStaking.connect(owner).stakeToken(500, 1)
        await expect(hyperStaking.connect(owner).claimReward(1)).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(hyperStaking, "stakeNotOver");

    });
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or is there no support for custom errors as of yet

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you sure your query will throw an error? What error is it throwing right now?

Answer (score 1):

What error is it? I tried it by myself and see the error `Invalid Chai property: revertedWithCustomError`.
Did you try to change `revertedWithCustomError` => `revertedWith` like below?

```
 it("Should not unstake if the time is not completed", async function () {
        await testToken.connect(owner).transfer(hyperStaking.address, 1000)
        await hyperStaking.connect(owner).stakeToken(500, 1)
        await expect(hyperStaking.connect(owner).claimReward(1)).to.be.revertedWith("stakeNotOver");

    });
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try surely